# Line of code missing ";" error

Tags: php

I am getting an error on line 49 below is line of code

Exact error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NEW, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/banking/onlinebanking/processdeposit.php on line 49

```
enter code here

<?php 


require_once('../header.inc.php');
require_once('../class/database.class.php');
require_once('../class/person.class.php'); 
require_once('../websiteconfig.inc.php');
require_once('../class/bankaccount.class.php');



/*Start Session*/
session_start();

$currentMember = unserialzed($_SESSION['currentMember']);

/*Initialize variables*/
$depositamount = $_POST['depositamount_dollars'] . '.' . $_POST['depositamount_cent'];

$account = $_POST['account'];
$errors[]=array();


/*Error Handling*/
if($depositamount_dollars==''){
$errors[] = 'Please enter a valid dollars amount for your deposit.';
}

/*Error Handling*/
if($depositamount_cents==''){
$errors[] = 'Please enter a valid cents amount for your deposit.';

}

if($account==0){
$errors[] =  'Please select an account.';
}

/*Check if errors exist*/

$db = new Database;
$bankaccount = new Bankaccount;
$bankaccount->connection =$db->connection;

/*Process Deposit*/
$newbalance = $bankaccount->deposit($currentMember->memberid, $account,     $depositamount);    


echo '<h3>Deposit Completed</h3>' . "\n";
```

Below is line 49

```
echo '<p>A deposit of ' .money_format('%i' , $depositamount) . 'to Account #' .$account . ' .The new balance is: ' . money_format('%i' , $newbalance) . '.</p>';
} else {



echo '<h1>Deposit Errors!</h1>' . "\n";
echo '<ul id="error_list">' . "\n";

foreach($errors As $errors) {
}
echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with those lines. Show your code together and the exact error message.

Comment: could it be that you have php4 on server , and are writing code for php5 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an error about missing ";" , then the mistake is usually in a line above.

Comment: the mistake above is only a echo statement.  I could not get the echo statement to render though so I have commented it out.

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be an `if` statement that the `else` block belongs to.

Comment: The else block is above on the split..

Comment: Please post the portion of code that has the starting `if` because it's nowhere in either of the code blocks you have up now.